# SQL запрос UPDATE множественный в Visual Studio на c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Есть приложение с БД Access. Нужно чтоб по запросу SQL UPDATE SET изменял все боксы, не могу додумать как сделать обновление всех , могу только одного (код вставлю ниже)

```
int kod = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);// переменную код сохранится то значение которое ввели в текст бокс
string query = "UPDATE Воспитанники SET ФИО ='" + textBox3.Text + "' WHERE Код = " + kod;
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);// в созданную переменную команда вставляем запрос переменную кверти и после указываем переменную по БД
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // удаление
MessageBox.Show("Данные о воспитаннике успешно изменены "); 
this.воспитанникиTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Воспитанники);// чтоб просмотр обновлялся
```

[image: Картинка БД]

Answer (score 2):

У тебя в Update только ФИО, надо в запрос добавить также другие поля:

```
string query = "UPDATE Воспитанники SET ФИО = @FIO, пол = @pol, датарождения = @dr ... where Код = " + kod;
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FIO", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pol", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dr ", textBox6.Text);
    ...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close(); //con это твое подключение к БД
```

Comment: вместо `...` добавь остальные поля сам, так как не знаю как они у тебя в бд называются, но думаю общий смысл понятен

Comment: Я чет видимо подтупливаю, но выдает ошибку "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции UPDATE." . Извиняюсь за тупость , я просто только начала изучать. Ошибка в данной строке  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: отредактируй вопрос и добавь туда твой код, который ты переделал